# org.alfresco.web.bean.repository.Repository; this class is not found in alfresco maven project how can i fix this

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

'org.alfresco.web.bean.repository.Repository'  this class is not found in alfresco maven project how can i fix it.

```
SearchParameters parameters = new SearchParameters();
parameters.addStore(Repository.getStoreRef());
parameters.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);
parameters.setQuery(query.toString());
```

as shown in above code i want to declare `SearchParameter` object for this i need repository store reference using this `Repository.getStoreRef()` method.

i am using mavem 2.1.1 all in one project for alfresco.

Comment: it seems like a dependency problem. make sure you have the right pom config, are you connected to the alfresco artifacts? Post a copy of your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your tagged your Question with *alfresco-share* tag! Are you attempting to manage (QUERY, CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) repo content from share tier ?

If so, you should be either using CMIS/RESTful api to query your repo. Remember alfresco share is just a webclient for your alfresco repo and has no direct access to the data.

You can also change your webscript location into a repo-amp project, that way dependencies will be picked and recognized.

Comment: its java webscript and its written at repo-amp means alfresco side